# NSBatchDeleteRequest leaving bad relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsbatchdeleterequest

I have a `Project` object that has a to-many relationship to `Image`, the delete rules are set up as Cascade for `project.images` and Nullify for `image.project`. In this case I need to clear out the attached images but leave the project itself intact. There are a lot of images so I want to use a batched delete to get them all in one go.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Image"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"project = %@", project];
NSBatchDeleteRequest *delete = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request];
delete.resultType = NSBatchDeleteResultTypeObjectIDs;
NSError *error;
NSBatchDeleteResult *result = [context.persistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:delete withContext:context error:&error];
if (error) {
    // todo
}
[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:@{NSDeletedObjectsKey : [result result]} intoContexts:@[context]];

NSLog(@"images: %@", project.images); // Still has all the images (they are now flagged as isDeleted)

[context save:&error];

NSLog(@"images: %@", project.images); // Still has all the images...
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html) the `mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave` line should take care of updating the context but this doesn't seem to happen.

One more thing, I know I can set `project.images = nil` and this does the job, but can't be used in a case when I am only deleting a subset of the images.

Edit: I have investigated further and have more info.

The issue occurs when `project.images` are faults. If I force them all to fault in then the relationships will successfully updated when the delete goes through. If I leave them as faults then the relationship is untouched and will now point to non-existent objects.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32831891/826716).

Comment: The first comment to that answer says that it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In `mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave` try including the `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` with the project's `objectID`.

```
[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:@{NSUpdatedObjectsKey : @[project.objectID], NSDeletedObjectsKey : [result result]} intoContexts:@[context]];`
```